# Compare spanish char in C

Tags: c

I need to compare every char of a string to another char and change this char `'á'` to `'a'`.
Here is what i have. 
Im getting this error: `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
         if(word[i] == 'á'){`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){

char word[50] = "básica";    
int i;

for(i = 0; i < strlen(word);i++){
    if(word[i] == 'á'){
        word[i] = 'a';
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: also never use `strlen(word)` in the for loop. Save it before the loop to avoid calling strlen again and again

Comment: It depends. 

`á` may take 1,2,3 or 4 bytes - it depends on the source code encoding here.

If it took only 1 byte (using some ASCII extended encoding), OP's code would have worked.

Comment: Although it's marked as duplicate there's no accepted answer in the related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is á occupies more than one character, So we have to do this in a string. Here, `sizeof("á")` returns one more than the number of characters that á occupies (the terminating null).

Let's try this:

```
char wordoutput[50];
int j;
int k;
for(i = 0, j < 0; i < strlen(word); i ++){
    int match = 1;
    for (k = 0; match && k < sizeof("á") - 1; k++)
        if (!word[i+k] || word[i+k] == "á"[k])
            match = 0;
    if (match)
        wordoutput[j++] = word[i];
    else {
        i += sizeof("á") - 2;
        wordoutput[j++] = 'a';
    }
}
wordoutput[j++] = 0;
```

We build up the string in wordoutput, replacing all á with a in the process.